# Import modules for a class using method of the same class

Tags: python, class, import

I am designing a python class where I would write a method, say `import_modules()`, to which I would be passing a list of modules to be imported in this class. Is it possible to `import` these modules at runtime for the same class?

```
class Base():
  def import_modules(self,modules):
     #import all the passed modules into this class

  def use_module(self):
     imported_module.some_function()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import modules at runtime by using __import__ and set the property of an object by using __setattr__ (name, object)

```py
class Base():
    def import_modules(self,modules):
        for m in modules:
            self.__setattr__(m, __import__(m))

    def use_module(self):
        print(self.sys.platform)

b = Base()
b.import_modules(['sys'])
b.use_module()
```